# How to use utf-8 and latin encoding in database.yml rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding, utf-8, ruby-on-rails-4

I have database.yml in rails4

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: test
  username: 
  password:

But I want to use
```

> utf8 and latin

encoding together, please let me know how can I do this if it is possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This seems like a strange thing to want to do: you will create complication for yourself.  Mind if I ask why you want to do this?  Why not just use utf8?  It contains all the latin characters.

Comment: You simply should not do that, but if you REALLY want you can create a separate connection with different encoding.